# Windows global variables in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

Is there any windows global variables that can be used to read/write data? 
And Can i access windows global variables from web application ?

Comment: what do you meant by **Windows global variables**

Comment: @SriramSakthivel; windows environment variables, dynamic variables e.g. %ComputerName% used for storing computer name in windows

Comment: do you mean `session` variable or `cookies` ?

Comment: @zey; No i mean windows environment variables, e.g in my above comment

Answer (score 2):

You mean environment variables? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can store strings in it, by I wouldn't store too much data there.